# Why does hashmap split method need to determine if (hiHead! = Null) before loHead.treeify (tab)

Tags: java, hashmap

When I read the hashmap split method source code, I found a piece of source code：

```
    final void split(HashMap<K,V> map, Node<K,V>[] tab, int index, int bit) {
        TreeNode<K,V> b = this;
        // Relink into lo and hi lists, preserving order
        TreeNode<K,V> loHead = null, loTail = null;
        TreeNode<K,V> hiHead = null, hiTail = null;
         ....
        if (loHead != null) {
            if (lc <= UNTREEIFY_THRESHOLD)
                tab[index] = loHead.untreeify(map);
            else {
                tab[index] = loHead;
                if (hiHead != null) // (else is already treeified)
                    loHead.treeify(tab);
            }
        }
       .......
    }
```

I can't understand why using loHead.treeify (tab); before, if (hiHead! = Null) judgment is needed. First of all, my understanding is that hashmap is used in a single thread, so I can't think of any relationship between hiHead and loHead. The official comment is "else is already treeified."

Answer (score 0):

The input to the method is a tree bin to be split. If all entries in that bin fall into one or the other split sets (i.e. they all have the same value for the newly added hash bit), then the input tree is already correct. It can just be reused as-is by making its root the new bin value with the other being empty.